# IIS 6 app pool management

Tags: iis, iis-6, application-pool

Create a appp pool, create a web application in the default seb site and assign it to the app pool. Now, if you expand the app pool node in IIS, you will see the new application  Normally, if you want to decomission the web applicaiton, you delete it from within IIS.  When that happens it gets unassocated from the App Pool.  If you refresh the app pool the web app will no longer be in list of apps asociated to that pool.

If someone decides to delete the web application through the file system, IIS isn't able to update the metabase, so now you can't see the web app in the default web site, but it still appears under the app pool.  Is there any way to refresh the metabase to remove old configuration that is 'orphaned'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've run into that, I call it ghosting!

I've seen it happen if you delete any folder that is an application without first removing it as an application.

If you just recreate the structure that was there and then remove it from being an application before deleting it you will eliminate it.

More interesting: If you convert the site to IIS 7.5 it will be created there during the conversion and then you can just delete it normally.